# mysql Group by : Slow query

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is my query

```
SELECT file_id, file_name, file_date, file_email
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM `file`
      ORDER BY file_date DESC
     ) AS t
WHERE file_domains = ''
GROUP BY file_name
ORDER BY file_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

primary key is file_id and index is file_name. Records about 900k
It took about 2 seconds in my local computer.
Is there any optimize for this query?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: What's the purpose of the sub-query? And if you select by file_domains, there should be an index on this column (unless most rows have an empty value).

Comment: 900,000 records in 2 seconds seems fast to me.

Comment: where are you aiming for, time wise?

Comment: It's weird, your `GROUP BY` should contains at least all columns you select.

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert 
[code]id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 90878  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2  DERIVED  file  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 90878  Using filesort[/code]

There're some duplicate records on file_name on different date (file_date). also file_domains most rows have an empty value. I need want to get like distinct file_name with newest file_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query uses a non-standard "feature" (mistake: one non-standard and one semi-standard feature) of MySQL and there is no guarantee that it will not break in future versions of MySQL, when the optimizer will be clever enough to understand that the subquery is redundant.

Add an index on `(file_domains, file_name, file_date)` and try this version:

```
SELECT f.file_id, f.file_name, f.file_date, f.file_email
FROM 
   `file` AS f
  JOIN
    ( SELECT file_name
          ,  MAX(file_date) AS max_file_date
      FROM `file`
      WHERE file_domains = ''
      GROUP BY file_name
      ORDER BY max_file_date DESC
      LIMIT 0 , 100
     ) AS fm
  ON  fm.file_name = f.file_name
  AND fm.max_file_date = f.file_date
ORDER BY f.file_date DESC ;
```

Comment: There is no need for the `order by` in the subquery. And the `limit` should be in the outer query.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` should be together. And since I have them in the internal query, there is no need to put them in the external.

Answer (score 0):

This intermediate query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `file`
ORDER BY file_date DESC
```

Fetches 900k records and orders by date, that might be slow.

Comment: There're some duplicate records on file_name on different date (file_date). also file_domains most rows have an empty value.
I need want to get like distinct file_name with newest file_date